# IndexedDB getAll convert to Blob and ArrayBuffer then revert back

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, arraybuffer

I am trying to learn IndexedDB and Blobs/ArrayBuffers and having difficulty in converting back from Blobs to Objects.

So far I have been able to download all store data from IndexedDB with getAll() and convert the data to Blob and ArrayBuffer. My issue is trying to convert back from Blob to the Array of 5 objects (Blob.text() returns a string of 'object Object'). How can I go about this?

db.js

```
//uses getAll() with no cursor
function getAllStoreData(db_ = db, transc, storeName, query) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        let tx =  db_.transaction([`${transc}`], 'readonly');
        try {
            let store =  tx.objectStore(`${storeName}`);  
            let req = store.getAll(query)
            let data = [];
            req.onsuccess = function(event) {
                data.push(req.result);             
                resolve(data);
            }
            req.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log("error with getall()");
                reject(new Error(`Unable to retrieve ${storeName}`));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            reject(new Error (`Unable to retrieve store "${storeName}"`));
        }
    });
}
```

template_form.js

```
getAllStoreData(undefined, "forms", "forms").then(data => {
    let buffer;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof (data));
    const obj = new Blob([data]);
    console.log(obj);
    obj.arrayBuffer().then(bin => {
        buffer = new Uint8Array(bin);
        console.log(buffer);

        const returnObj = new Blob([buffer]);

        // let reader = new FileReader();
        // reader.onload = function() {
        //     console.log(reader.result);
        // }
        // reader.readAsText(returnObj);

        let objText = returnObj.text().then(text => {
            console.log(text);
            console.log(typeof (text));
        });
    })
})
```

output:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSc8b.png)

Comment: I sort of figured a solution by Stringify the 'obj' variable. const obj = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)]); Can then iterate over it

Comment: indexeddb is capable of storing array, objects typedarrays etc i would suggest that you use it instead of converting it to blobs.

Comment: @Endless That right, I am storing the data in my IndexedDB store in different types, object, and blob. I am trying to download the store data to a txt file so I was thinking that the best way was to convert the data to binary representation (Uint8Array) from a Blob as there a different data types in store. Then can convert back to IndexedDB from the txt file.